# Access elements inside of a remote modal with vue.js

Tags: bootstrap-modal, vue.js

I'm read through the vue.js docs, but I am confused about how to load a partial and bind it to the vue instance.

As an example, with bootstrap's js, I can load a remote modal like this:

```
<a href="{{URL::to('retention/modals/campaign')}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add New Campaign</a>
```

This loads a partial inside of my

```
<div id="modal></div>
```

Using vue, I have made the modal a component, and the partial will load, but I cannot get the partial's elements to bind to the vue instance. So any events inside of the modal such as

```
v-on:click.prevent="say('hi')"
```

won't work.

How do I bind elements added to the page after the vue instance is created?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$mount`

Parent vue instance declaration:

```
var vm = new Vue({...})
```

New Instance: (have this run after the dynamic content is loaded into your container)

```
var newContentInstance = vm.$addChild({ 
     el: '#modal', 
     data: function data() {
          return { something: '' };
     } 
});
newContentInstance.$mount();
```